# Python output flushed through ts only at the end of the script

Tags: python, timestamp, pipe

When I pipe a Python script through `ts` in order to prepend timestamps at the beginning of each line, it seems that the whole script is executed before `ts` gets any of the output.

Here's an example:

```
$ cat sleep.py
import time
print("First line")
time.sleep(1)
print("Second line")
$ python < sleep.py | ts -s "%.s"
1.002681 First line
1.003763 Second line
```

It was already more than a second when the first line was processed by `ts`.  I would expect something like this instead:

```
0.002681 First line
1.003763 Second line
```

I'm using `bash` 3.2.57 and Python 3.8.2 on macOS Catalina 10.15.7. `ts` comes from `moreutils 0.64` through `brew`.